# Custom Email validation directive not displaying the validation result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to verify whether the email exists in my db or not.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('emailValidApp', [])
app.directive('validateEmail', function($http) {
       return {
         restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {
                var ngModel = ctrls;
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(email) {
                    var url = 'http://xxxx:8081/xxxx/user/getemail?email='+email;

                       $http.get(url)
                       .then(function(data) {
                          if (data.email_valid) {
                               ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', false);
                          } else {
                               ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', true);
                          }
                        }, function(error) {
                             ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', false);
                        });
                });
            }
        }
});
app.controller('SignUpController', function($scope) {

$scope.signMeup;
 });
```

View.jsp

```
<form name="signupForm" ng-submit="signMeUp()">
<div>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email_addr" ng-model="info.email" validate-email/>
<span ng-show="signupForm.email_addr.$validEmail">
<p>This email address already exists.</p>
</span>
</div>
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

I am able to see response in my console that whether the email is valid or not but not on my view.

Please help me out

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error just by modifying below part in my js[data.data]

```
$http.get(url)
      .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.data);
                           if (data.data) {
                               console.log("inside if : "+ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', false));
                               ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', false);
                          } else {
                              console.log("inside else :" +ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', true))
                               ngModel.$setValidity('validEmail', true);
                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<span ng-show="signupForm.email_addr.$invalid">` instead of `<span ng-show="signupForm.email_addr.$validEmail">`. It should resolve your problem.

Comment: It is showing up but that is only for validation eighter the email is typed according to the norms with @ etc.So when i type an email already existed in my db it doesn't show up.It shows only when i type the email in incorrect format.